# Not fetching email from .json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when sending api request for

```
http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login
```

I cant get the email and it is showing following error:

```
const email = req.body.email;
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at loginController
```

**code:**

index.js file

```
const users = require("../models/user");
const signupController = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("signupController called");

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(403).send("Email and Passwords are required");
    return;
  }

  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  users.push({
    id,
    email,
    password,
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    id,
  });
};
const loginController = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("loginController called");

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if (!req.body.email || !password) {
    res.status(403).send("Email and Passwords are required");
    return;
  }
  const user = users.find((item) => item.email === email);
  if (!user) {
    res.status(403).send("User not found");
    return;
  }

  if (users.password !== password) {
    res.status(401).send("Incorrect password");
    return;
  }

  res.status(200).json(user);
};

module.exports = { signupController, loginController };
```

**json input**
`{ email:'nasta@gmail.com', password:'1423' };`

I tried printing all emails and passwords in module file they are printed but login signup controllers not working and the server is crashing on calling it.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined (reading 'email')` is because `req.body` is undefined. This means that the request body is not being parsed properly.

To fix this, you need to add a middleware that parses the request body. You can use the `body-parser` library for this purpose. Here's an example:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// ...

// Add the body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// ...
```

Make sure to add this code before you define your routes.

Comment: Thank you for help but now it is giving the incorrect password . My **user.js** file is const users =[{
   ```id:'134',
    email:'next@gmail.com',
    password:'1234'
},{
    id:'141',
    email:'nasta@gmail.com',
    password:'1423'
}]
module.exports=users;```